# Can I remove time stamp from string %%order_valid_from%% and %%order_valid_to%%

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, string

When we use the strings `%%order_valid_from%%` and `%%order_valid_to%%` the date is followed by a time stamp. We wish to remove this time stamp as the stamp is defined in AM/PM and in Denmark we don't use that.

How do I remove the time stamp from the two strings?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you retrieve the data from a data extension but you can format the date based on the locales. For example:

```
FormatDate(Now(), "MMM dd, yyyy", "HH:mm:ss.tt", "da_DK")
```

Its output is something like:

```
dec 02, 2017 20:37:20
```

You can change Now() function with your field name.

Comment: Thank you. And where would you place the function?

Comment: Could you please tell me where you retrieve the data for order_valid_from and order_valid_to? From a landing page or data extension?

Comment: A data extension

Comment: Can you please share its screenshot with the fields in it for better understanding?